# Sequentiality of largest vector topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

I know that the largest vector topology on countable dimensional vector space is sequential (i.e. every sequentially closed set is closed). Does it keep for the arbitrary vector space?

In countable dimensional case I can describe structure of largest vector topology (it coincides with the largest locally convex topology), but I don't know anything about uncountable dimensional case.

(Largest vector topology on a vector space is the supremum of set of all vector topologies on it.)

Comment: It would help if you explained more precisely what topology you're speaking about.

Comment: You should keep to a single identity really. Please consider registering. And addressing the earlier comment.

Comment: What do you mean by "vector topology"?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev Largest vector topology on a vector space is a supremum of set of all vector topologies on it.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov The topology is called vector if operations of addition and multiplication are continious.

Comment: It seems to me I saw something similar here: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01234921 Perhaps, this will help.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov The theorem claims that the finite topology of uncountable vector space is not a vector topology.

Comment: Ah, OK, I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a linear space $X$ with a Hamel basis $H$ the largest vector topology seems to coincide with the topology of free linear topological space over the discrete space $H$. If this is true, then we can apply known results on the sequentiality of free linear topological spaces, see e.g. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04857
Theorem 10.12.4 of this paper implies that for a discrete space $X$ the free linear topological space $Lin(X)$ over $X$ is sequential iff $Lin(X)$ is a $k$-space iff $X$ is countable.

Comment: I proved that it's true. Thank you!

Comment: Then close this question as being answered. By the way, the equivalence of the sequentiality and the k-space property in $Lin(X)$ follows from the metrizablity of compact sets in $Lin(X)$.